# How to detect if photo is black and white, grey or sepia in JS?

Tags: javascript, graphics

I would like to detect if an image is black and white, grey or sepia using JavaScript. How to do it?

Comment: 1 way, could be improved; extract all colors into an array, make it unique. if the r,g,and b values of each pixel are the same, it's grey. if they are also all 0 or 255, it's halftone (b+w). if the sub-pixel color values for all pixels are within, say 50, and B is the least value, it's probably sepia.

Comment: @dandavis it's a nice clue. But i have noticed, if i am not wrong, that you assume me asking about grey means a photo of one color grey. But i mean a photo with different shades of grey color. Correct me if i wrong please.

Comment: no, i meant that each RGB pixel will be something like (5,5,5) or (122,122,122)...